# How to queue APIs requests with RabbitMQ

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

I would like to queue requests made by mobile application that uses API to send some data to the server.

The scenario for now is like this:

1. Mobile app sends a request with some data
2. I need to get the data, validate it (a few DB queries) and save to a few tables in DB.
3. I need to return OK response to mobile app or bad request with erros list in case the validation has failed.

Now if I have 1 000 requests like this in 3 seconds my server will collapse.

I would like to use RabbitMQ to queue those requests. But what should I do with a response? I cannot send OK after RabbitMQ has received the message cause I don't know if the validation will pass. So mobile app will wait until RabbitMQ message will be properly consumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a solution to your problem:

1. The client sends a request
2. The server queues the request and generate a unique identifier that belongs to the queued request, and then sends a response containing the generated identifier with 202 (Accepted) status code that means the request has been queued or submitted on the server but there is no response yet.
3. The client subscribes to the generated identifier on a message broker
4. After a queued request finished on the server it will publish a response to the message broker based on the generated identifier for a request
5. The client will receive published response on the subscribing identifier

Tips:

- I use EMQTT for the message broker. Another option would be Rabbitmq MQTT plugin